# Vuex not keeping currentUser state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

So I am Building a Vue.js SPA using Rails 6 api as the backend and Vue-cli (legacy webpack template)

When I sign a user in, everything works fine, I can see the users details, it sets my setCurrentUser mutation and state, as soon as I click away from my dashboard, I loose all my user's state. the vue dev tool panel essentially shows everything reset back to false.

I am rather new to Vue / Vuex so this may be an oversight on my part.

My signin method to grab the current user:

```
 methods: {
    signin () {
      let formData = new FormData()
      formData.append('user[email]', this.user.email)
      formData.append('user[password]', this.user.password)

      this.$http.plain.post('/signin', formData, { emulateJSON: true })
        .then(response => this.signinSuccessful(response))
        .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error))
    },
    signinSuccessful (response) {
      if (!response.data.csrf) {
        this.signinFailed(response)
        return
      }
      this.$http.plain.get('/api/v1/me')
        .then(meResponse => {
          this.$store.commit('setCurrentUser', { currentUser: meResponse.data, csrf: response.data.csrf })
          this.error = ''
          this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
          this.flashMessage.show({
            status: 'info',
            title: 'Signed In',
            message: 'Signin successful, welcome back!'
          })
        })
        .catch(error => this.signinFailed(error))
    },
    signinFailed (error) {
      this.user.error = (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.error)
      this.$store.commit('unsetCurrentUser')
    },
    checkSignedIn () {
      if (this.$store.state.signedIn) {
        this.$router.replace('/dashboard')
      }
    }
  }
```

This image shows the api call to signin completes and returns the user object. 
[image: Network Console Showing Successful Signin]

This image shows the Vue Panel sets the currentUser state and has the user object
[image: Vue panel Shows state]

Now when I go to do a page refresh or move away from my dashboard, I loose everything that was in state.

[image: Loss of State]

So like I said I'm brand new to Vuex, I have tried to use Vue.set and $set on my mutations in store.js but this did not remedy the problem either..?

Here is my store.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    currentUser: {},
    signedIn: false,
    csrf: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setCurrentUser (state, { currentUser, csrf }) {
      state.currentUser = currentUser
      state.signedIn = true
      state.csrf = csrf
    },
    unsetCurrentUser (state) {
      state.currentUser = {}
      state.signedIn = false
      state.csrf = null
    },
    refresh (state, csrf) {
      state.signedIn = true
      state.csrf = csrf
    }
  },
  getters: {
    isOwner (state) {
      return state.currentUser && state.currentUser.role === 'owner'
    },
    isManager (state) {
      return state.currentUser && state.currentUser.role === 'manager'
    },
    isAdmin (state) {
      return state.currentUser && state.currentUser.role === 'admin'
    },
    isUser (state) {
      return state.currentUser && state.currentUser.role === 'user'
    },
    isSignedIn (state) {
      return state.signedIn === true
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    createPersistedState({

    })
  ]
})
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @M.Gara i should have listed that in the question, I have tried to use that, but could not get it working, no errors logged but was not creating the cookie

Comment: You should not do a refresh. Because refresh will clear the Vue instance and create a new one. If you want to persist the data even after a refresh, you should use browser `local storage`. And FYI, replace `$router.replace` with `$router.push` so that the browser history gets updated.

Comment: He is using `vuex-persistedstate` -> he is using localStorage
Check your browser Dev Tools - localStorage. Are there data after page reload ?

Answer (score 0):

Add plugins: [createPersistedState()], when creating store instance

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
          plugins: [createPersistedState()],}
```